# how to project fields using another field's value in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo document like this:

```
{"_id": {"$oid":"xx"} ,"start": "a", "elements": {"a":"large object", "b": "large object"}
```

My expected query result is to project only the start element, in this case, it is {"elements.a:"large object"}. But with the value of "start" unknow before the query, I don't know how to write the query.

2 undesirable alternatives:

- One way I could figure is to query start once with _id, and project for start to get "a", and another for elements.a。（
- Another way is query all, and get the start element in code. But I don't want to query all at once for the document may be very large)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @ngShravil.py I have added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operators.

The below query will be helpful:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      elements: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$elements"
            },
            as: "e",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$e.k",
                "$start"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "elements": {
      "a": "large object"
    }
  }
]
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-JdwIxQEfkW)

I hope, this is what you want.

Comment: this works！Thanks! I have a follow-up question about the burden of this operation for online mongo, will this kind of operator slows down the db?